# How do i add Value to my listbox item name, so i can use it in a math function? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

How do i add Value to my listbox item name, so i can use it in a math function?

I have a list consisting of a few names, now i want to add a value (numbers) to those items in order to use it in a math function.

Being precise, i have 3 items: Bankloan, Kreditloan and Miscloan. I want to add value to those items in my list box, so i can get the total Loan in a math function.

Please i need help, i have tried a lot now, and now i am from  scratch again :/

```
Test is not worth getting on here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize the index of the text items in the list with an array of numbers:

```
Private mItemValues(2) As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Bankloan"
         mItemValues(0) = 111

        .AddItem "Kreditloan"
        mItemValues(1) = 222

        .AddItem "Miscloan"
        mItemValues(2) = 333
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If (ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0) Then
        MsgBox "no selection"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value = " & mItemValues(ComboBox1.ListIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I hide columns for data I want associated with the record, but don't want to display.
Works great with database table primary keys that are integer values useless to the end user.

```
filterQuery = "SELECT ID, [PROJECT NAME] FROM PROJECTS_TABLE"
With Me.listbox1
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "0 in, 3 in"
    .RowSource = filterQuery
    .Requery
End With
```